# JQuery: .live() vs .delegate() for ajax:complete event on replaced elements

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 in a Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 app and wanting to switch from `.live()` to `.delegate()` (with plans to upgrade to jQuery 1.7 and use `.on()`). I'm using the `:remote => true` option in Rails to send ajax requests and trying to set up a handler for the responses using the `ajax:complete` event. These ajax requests will often remove/replace the element that actually triggered the request.

The problem I'm having is that if an element is replaced by the ajax request, `.live()` seems to trigger the `ajax:complete` handler anyway when the request is done, but `.delegate()` does not (also, I did a little experiment with jQuery 1.7 and found that `.on()` does not work either).

Essentially, if the `ajax_link` element is replaced, this works:

```js
$(".ajax_link").live("ajax:complete", function(){
  //Do something...
});
```

But this does not:

```js
$("body").delegate(".ajax_link", "ajax:complete", function(){
  //Do something...
});
```

Any thoughts on why this is occurring? I read elsewhere on SO that `.delegate()` uses `.live()` behind the scenes so this behaviour is surprising to me. Also, any suggestions for a better way to approach this problem would be welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure why your second event handler isn't working, but `live` is equivalent to `$(document).delegate`, not `$('body').delegate`, if that's what you were thinking. Also, `live` uses `delegate` behind the scenes I believe, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, @jackwanders. Using `$(document)` did get it working, but I still don't understand why the `$("body")` version doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

With jquery 1.7 and also 1.8, triggering an event from a removed element will not bubble up to the document. So your callback handlers registered on either `body` or `document` will not be called.

To workaround this, you have to:

1. register your `complete` callback without a selector:

   ```
   $(document).on('ajax:complete', function() {
     // do something
   });
   ```
2. patch the `handleRemote` function in `rails.js` to trigger the event on the `document` if the element is detached from the document.

   replace:

   ```
     complete: function(xhr, status) {
       element.trigger('ajax:complete', [xhr, status]);
   ```

   with:

   ```
     complete: function(xhr, status) {
       if (element.parents().last().parent().get(0) == document)
         element.trigger('ajax:complete', [xhr, status]);
       else
         $(document).trigger('ajax:complete', [xhr, status]);
   ```

I put a comment on [issue #223 of rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/223#issuecomment-8427540) about that.

Comment: Thanks, Pascal. This is interesting, and I'll keep it mind if I decide to upgrade to jQuery 1.7 or 1.8. But I'm still using 1.6, and do you have any idea why the `$("body").delegate(...)` version I was trying didn't work (while `$(document).delegate(...)` does)?